# Tableau API Retrieving UserID

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I want to build a webpage that hosts an imbedded Tableau workbook along with several other controls - one of which needs to be fed via AJAX from an external database. That external control needs to retrieve data on the basis of the UserId being served by the Tableau Server which hosts the imbedded workbook:  [image: below]

I've got the webpage built with the embedded workbook and all of the controls except the external database fed control working. I am able to call this webpage directly from the Tableau Server after logging in. My problem is retrieving the UserId upon load so that I can make the AJAX call to populate the remaining control.

Is there a way strictly using the JavaScript API to capture the UserId?

Comment: I am assuming that by userid you mean the DB userid used by the data-source of your embedded view/workbook, and NOT the tableau server userid used to load the embedded view. Correct?

Comment: Just the opposite. I AM looking for the Tableau server userid - the same one as seen in the Postgres repository in the workgroups database in the system_users table field: auth_user_id.

Comment: Actually, I can get by with the same as systems_users:name